# All combinations of lists using unique indexes in Python

Tags: python, list, find

I have N lists of 3 elements. I want to find all combinations between them that don't use the same index twice. Each combination must always have 3 items.

Example:

```
list1 = [l11, l12, l13]

list2 = [l21, l22, l23]

list3 = [l31, l32, l33]
```

All combinations possible:

```
combinaison1 = l11, l22, l33

combinaison2 = l11, l23, l32

combinaison3 = l12, l21,l33

combinaison4= l12, l23, l31

combinaison5=l13, l21, l32

combinaison6= l13, l22, l31
```

BUT I don't want:

```
BADcombinaison = l11,l21,l32
```

How can I do that in python?

Comment: To clarify: the last digit is always unique in the combination.

Comment: what about `combinasion2`?

Comment: you have used the same elements twice

Comment: `l11, l23, l31` is using the same index twice.

Comment: It's not the same index for me. 
l11 use the index 0 in his list
l23 use the index 1 in his list
l31 use the index 2 in his list

Comment: It's a mistake ben, I've made the correction

Comment: Please show valid combinaison's for just list1 and list2 (n=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only up to 3 items from 3 or more lists, the first step is to find k-permutations of the list of lists with k-3. I.e. `permutations(lists, 3)`. From there you don't actually have to permute the indexes too, because you want unique indexes. (Note: this allows variable number of lists and also a variable length of the lists, but the lengths of all input and output lists are equal).

Essentially instead of trying to permute indexes, the indexes are just (0, 1, 2) since you specify no repetition of indexes, and the lists are permuted.

```
from itertools import permutations

# number of lists may vary (>= length of lists)
list1 = ["l11", "l12", "l13"]
list2 = ["l21", "l22", "l23"]
list3 = ["l31", "l32", "l33"]
list4 = ["l41", "l42", "l43"]
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

# lenths of lists must be the same and will be the size of outputs
size = len(lists[0])
for subset in permutations(lists, size):
    print([sublist[item_i] for item_i, sublist in enumerate(subset)])
```

Comment: Thanks Jason but for example with 4 lists... your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Matt in your question you never used a number other than 3. Why would we expect 4?

Comment: I've said, "I've n list", the number of lists is not always 3. I can have 3,4,5,6 lists.

Comment: Updated for varying N.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot Jason! Your solution is very nice.